# Reset User Password on Ubuntu Terminal in Windows 10 Environment

Tags: password, windows-10, password-recovery

I am using Ubuntu on Windows, downloaded from the Microsoft Store. I created a user password, but it appears I either forgot it or typed it in wrong. For sudo commands, my user password is not working.

Since I cannot reboot the system as Linux using Grub to reset the password, is there another way to reset my user password without re-installing the app (I have several applications already set up)?

Answer (score 5):

This was really tricky when I've faced this situation myself and solved it eventually.

1. First Start your "Ubuntu" and type `cat /etc/passwd/` and note the number UID and exit the terminal.
   Like below in the terminal

   ```
   mandheer@WKWIN1754031:~$ cat /etc/passwd
   root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
   daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
   bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
   mandheer:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/mandheer:/bin/bash
   ```
2. Note down the userid against "root" user and logged in user ("mandheer" in this case)

   - root:x:**0:0**:root:/root:/bin/bash
   - mandheer:x:**1000:1000**:,,,:/home/mandheer:/bin/bash
   - for `root` user it's `0` and for `mandheer` user it's `1000`

   > WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) uses registry to identify some values including logged in user at initial start.
3. Just go ahead to `win+R` , then type `regedit` which will open registry editor
   Navigate to :
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`
4. Check the installed distributions and navigate to 'Ubuntu' distribution.
5. Then, navigate to `"DefaultUid"`

   - Check it current value, it must be set to `1000` in decimal or `0x3e8` in hexadecimal
   - Set `"DefaultUid"` value to `0` as decimal for `root` user
   - Exit registry editor
6. Open 'Ubuntu' , it should start with root already logged in.

   - Then run command `passwd <User_name>` e.g. `#$passwd mandheer`
     Type new password and retype password.

     ```
     bash#>passwd <existing username> and press Enter  
     New password: <type your password here>  
     Retype password: <re enter password here>
     ```
7. Your existing username password is reset to new password now.

   - Exit command prompt
8. Repeat step 3 to 5 for existing user

   - Means, go to register editor and set the "DefaultUid" to previous value e.g `1000` as decimal for `mandheer` user
9. Start `Ubuntu` terminal again and it should login with your existing user without asking for password.

   - Type `$sudo su` to get root access.
   - Enter newly set password as in step 6 above.

Answer (score 3):

Open the command prompt, type either `ubuntu config --default-user root` or `lxrun /setdefaultuser root`. Hit Enter.

Next, open the Linux Bash shell and it will log you as root without asking a password. So you can then use the following command to reset your forgotten user password:

```
passwd user_name
```

When done, open the command prompt and run this command:

```
ubuntu config --default-user user_name
```

This will set your Linux Bash shell to run with your regular user.

Source: https://www.top-password.com/blog/forgot-linux-bash-password-in-windows-10/

Comment: In case you don't know your WSL username, you can follow the instruction on the following link:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/128056-list-users-windows-subsystem-linux-wsl-distro-windows-10-a.html#:~:text=1%20Run%20the%20WSL%20distro%20%28ex%3A%20"Ubuntu"%29%20you,user%20accounts%20in%20this%20WSL%20distro%20%28ex%3A%20"Ubuntu"%29.

Answer (score 1):

I have WSL enabled and ubuntu installed on my pc. According to MS Docs site*, I ran PowerShell (`powershell.exe`) and executed `wsl -u root` and then executed `passwd <my-username-on-ubuntu>`. I entered new password after the prompt and reset completed. That's all for me. I am using Win10 [Version 10.0.19041.572] and running "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"

Ref:
*: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support#forgot-your-password

Comment: The answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1146987/475325 did not work for me because `ubuntu` was not a command on the regular command prompt. However, I could run `wsl -u root` on PowerShell. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows Powershell or Command Prompt one can login to the wsl default account with root access.

```
wsl --user root
```

For password change use the following command.

```
passwd
```

Or one can use the following command by passing the username of the user whose password needs to be changed. In this case its your username for the distro.

```
passwd username
```

The above two commands will ask you for the new password. Enter your new password two times you should see successful token update message.

After that you can logout from the wsl by pressing `ctrl+d`. Incase you have multiple distribution installed and don't know the name to the one you want to change password. Use the following command to list down the installed distributions.

```
wsl -l
```

For logging into desired distribution use the name from the list. For Ubuntu 20.04 the command would be:

```
wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 --user root
```

For CentOS7 the command would be:

```
wsl -d CentOS7 --user root
```